# Can any one explain why i am getting undefined output on this leetcode problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matching

back again with another leetcode issue. i cant get my functions or my for each loop to return a value, when I do so it still shows up as undefined

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isValid = function(s) {
   
  let  opposingParens = {
    "(" : ")",
    "[" : "]",
    "{" : "}"
  }
  let splitChars = s.split('');
   
  let isTruthy = false
  let opposingParensFunc = (paren) => {
      
    if(splitChars[1] == opposingParens[paren] || splitChars[splitChars.length -1] == opposingParens[paren]) {
      isTruthy = true
    }
    return isTruthy
  }
   
       
  splitChars.forEach((char,i) => {
    return opposingParensFunc(char)
  })
};
```

1. Your input "()"
2. Output undefined
3. Expected true

Thank you for your help.

Comment: indentation was hard to read here. As a Stack Overflow usage tip, and in case it wasn't your original indentation, I suggest to copy paste the original code and just add triple backticks ( ``` ) as a line before and after, instead of the button "code formatting" that adds some spaces in front. If it was your original indentation, then I suggest to be more consistent about this, see edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has no `return` statement. The one that you do have is providing a return value for another function: the function that you provide to `forEach`. But that is not determining the return value of the main function. It looks like you wanted to do the following *outside* any callback function:

```
return isThruthy;
```

NB: providing a return value in a `forEach` callback is useless, that value is never used by it.

However, your algorithm will not work in the general case, because you always compare a character with the one at index 1 and with the last character in the input. But note that the balancing closing bracket could be anywhere in the input. Think of "([]){}".

What you really need, is a stack. When you find an opening bracket, but its closing counter part on the stack, which indicates what you expect to find somewhere at the *right* of this opening bracket. If there is another opening bracket, then that one should be closed first, so we also push the corresponding closing bracket on the stack, ...etc.

When you find a closing bracket, you compare it with the one on the top of the stack. If they differ, then the input is invalid. If equal, you have a balancing pair, and can pop that info from the stack, ...etc.

When you reach the end of the input, you must also make sure that there are no more closing brackets that were expected. In other words, at that moment the stack should be empty.

Here is an implementation:

```
let brackets = {
    "(": ")",
    "[": "]",
    "{": "}",
};

var isValid = function(s) {
    let stack = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        let ch = s[i];
        let open = brackets[ch];
        if (open) stack.push(open);
        else if (ch !== stack.pop()) return false;
    }
    return !stack.length; // true when stack is empty, false otherwise
};
```

Comment: What exactly does ch !== stack.pop() do?

Comment: Very confused about this part

Comment: `stack.pop()` extracts the top value from the stack: that value is a closing bracket. Since `ch` was not an opening bracket (see `if`), it is also a closing one. The two should match. If not (`!==`), then it is not a valid input. For instance, when input is `"(]"`: first iteration puts the `(` on the stack. Second iteration pops it from the stack and compares it with `]`: mismatch!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var isValid = function(s) {

let  opposingParens = {
    "(" : ")",
    "[" : "]",
    "{" : "}"
}
let  splitChars = s.split('');

let isTruthy = false
let opposingParensFunc = (paren) => {
  
   if(splitChars[1] === opposingParens[paren] || splitChars[splitChars.length -1] === opposingParens[paren]  ){
    isTruthy = true
}
   return isTruthy
}
splitChars.forEach((char,i) =>{
    console.log(opposingParensFunc(char))
})  
};
isValid("()")
```

Like it was said earlier in the comments forEach() returns undefined and the expected answer here would be 2 true because forEach() is running twice.